# Встречено else, а ожидался оператор

Tags: pascal

Помогите пожалуйста, минут 30 смотрю в код и не понимаю где ошибка

Ошибка на строке 29 - Syntax error, ";" expected but "ELSE" found

```
PROCEDURE Print_tree(var Tr: tree; var sum: integer);
Var i,j: integer;
alreadyin: array[1..6] of string;
k: array[1..6] of integer;

Begin
    for j:=1 to 6 do alreadyin[j]:= '';
    for j:=1 to 6 do k[j]:= 1;

    If Tr <> nil then
    Begin
        Print_tree(Tr^.Right,sum); // рекурсивный вывод правой ветки

        for i := 1 to Tr^.amt do
            begin
                sum:= sum - 1; // чтобы после последнего слова поставить точку
                if sum <> 0 then
                    begin
                    //Write(Tr^.elem,',') // вывод самого элемента
                        for j:=1 to 6 do
                            begin
                                if (Tr^.elem) = alreadyin[j] then k[j]:= j+1; //break;
                                else if alreadyin[j] = '' then alreadyin[j]:= (Tr^.elem) //ошибка на этой строке
                            end;
                    end;

                else Write(Tr^.elem,'.') // нужное кол-во раз
            end;
        Print_tree(Tr^.Left,sum); /// левой ветки
        dispose(Tr) // удаление вершины для очистки памяти !(важно)!
    End;

End;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно убрать `;` в предыдущей строчке после `k[j]:= j+1;`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное